# is sys/dir.h a header file in c for UNIX systems

Tags: c, linux, header

I am studying Ch - UNIX system interface in K&R. In the book although there has not been a use of "sys/dir.h" header file but I have seen it being used somewhere on the net but compiler shows error when I try to include it so I am confused whether it is a part of C11 sttandard or not(I think C11 is the latest) for UNIX systems. Please also tell its use.

Comment: All header names of the form `<sys/abcdef.h>` are not part of standard C; none of the standard C headers includes a slash in the name (indeed, the only punctuation in the names is the `.` before the terminal `h`).  So any name such as `<sys/dir.h>` is not standard C.  Whether it is POSIX or some other standard is harder — you can look at the list of [POSIX headers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/head.html) to see whether a given name is part of POSIX (`<sys/dir.h>` isn't).  So you need to find out where it does come from — Google (and its relatives) are your friend.

Comment: Also notice that the directory reading code in K&R no longer works on the vast majority of extant file systems.  It is one of the parts that shows the book's age, I'm afraid.  You'd do better not bothering with that part of it — unless you can find a System V UFS (Unix File System) on which to practice.  There may be a few obscure and mostly obsolescent systems where they are available, but you're relatively unlikely to have access to one.  Use the code from `<dirent.h>` — `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()` et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the book says, `<sys/dir.h>` is from System V UNIX.

The C standard itself has no support for directories. POSIX defines the header `<dirent.h>`, which declares `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir`, among other things.

The system I use (Ubuntu) has a `<sys/dir.h>` header, presumably for backward compatibility. I wouldn't use it in new code.

Comment: The BSD (macOS) header `<sys/dir.h>` mainly includes `<dirent.h>`, contains `#define direct dirent` "for backwards compatibility", and redefines `DIRSIZ` in a complicated way.  I'd not be surprised to find that the Linux version is similar (though my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has no file `/usr/include/sys/dir.h` — I'm not sure where it comes from).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's a symlink to `../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/dir.h` in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and 18.04 LTS, provided by `libc6-dev-i386`.